# When using tidyr::unnest_wider(), how to name new columns based on chr vector

Tags: r, tidyr, unnest

I have the following data structure:

```r
library(tibble)

my_tbl <-
  tibble::tribble(
                   ~col_x,   ~col_y,
                   "a",      list(1, 2, 3),
                   "b",      list(4, 5, 6),
                   "c",      list(7, 8, 9)
                   )
```

And I want to use `tidyr::unnest_wider()` to separate `col_y` to columns. The names for those new columns should be taken from `animal_names` vector:

```r
animal_names <- c("dog", "cat", "zebra")
```

How can I utilize `unnest_wider()` to apply the names from `animal_names`, thereby avoiding the following naming warning:

```r
library(tidyr)

my_tbl %>%  
  unnest_wider(col_y)
#> New names:
#> * `` -> ...1
#> * `` -> ...2
#> * `` -> ...3
#> New names:
#> * `` -> ...1
#> * `` -> ...2
#> * `` -> ...3
#> New names:
#> * `` -> ...1
#> * `` -> ...2
#> * `` -> ...3
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   col_x  ...1  ...2  ...3
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a         1     2     3
#> 2 b         4     5     6
#> 3 c         7     8     9
```

*desired output*

```r
## # A tibble: 3 x 4
##   col_x   dog   cat zebra
##   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
## 1 a         1     2     3
## 2 b         4     5     6
## 3 c         7     8     9
```

---

Please note that [@akrun suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58188805/6105259) to add names to the nested values *before* `unnest`ing.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

my_tbl %>%
  mutate(across(col_y, ~map(., .f = ~set_names(.x, animal_names)))) %>%
  unnest_wider(col_y)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#>   col_x   dog   cat zebra
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a         1     2     3
#> 2 b         4     5     6
#> 3 c         7     8     9
```

However, this is a redundant and expensive operation when we deal with large datasets. Can't we just apply names through `unnest_wider()`'s `names_repair` argument?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `names_repair` needs the full column names in addition to the column unnested.  So, we create a vector of names excluding the 'col_y' concatenated with 'animal_names' vector and use that in `names_repair`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
nm1 <- c(setdiff(names(my_tbl), 'col_y'), animal_names)
my_tbl %>%  
  unnest_wider(col_y, names_repair = ~ nm1) %>%
  suppressMessages
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  col_x   dog   cat zebra
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 a         1     2     3
2 b         4     5     6
3 c         7     8     9
```

Comment: Thanks, so simple. But I still get the annoying warning message. Why is that?

Comment: @Emman you meant the `New names:`.  I think the warning is triggered before the names_repair because the `list` column is not named

Comment: Oh, I really hoped that if I use `unnest_wider()` own arguments, the warning will not show.   Do you have an idea how we could silent the warning?

Comment: @Emman you may wrap with `suppressMessages(my_tbl %>%  
   unnest_wider(col_y, names_repair = ~ nm1))`

Comment: It is not a warning.  It is a message so it can be silenced with `suppressMessages`

Comment: very nice! it can even be added to the pipe after `unnest_wider()`

Comment: @Emman yes, it can be added.

Answer (score 0):

If you are annoyed by the message, you can use the argument `names_sep` (in recent version of tidyr, either 1.0 or 1.1), which will silent the message. Because you override the values with `names_repair`, you can set any arbitrary value to `names_sep=""`.

---

### author: mstigler
date: 2022-03-04
output: "reprex::reprex_document"
title: woody-kiwi_reprex.R

```r
library(tidyr)

my_tbl <-
  tibble::tribble(
    ~col_x,   ~col_y,
    "a",      list(1, 2, 3),
    "b",      list(4, 5, 6),
    "c",      list(7, 8, 9))

animal_names <- c("dog", "cat", "zebra")
nm1 <- c(setdiff(names(my_tbl), 'col_y'), animal_names)
my_tbl |>
  unnest_wider(col_y, names_repair = ~ nm1, names_sep = "")
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>   col_x   dog   cat zebra
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a         1     2     3
#> 2 b         4     5     6
#> 3 c         7     8     9
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>